# Is polymorphism exclusive to OOP?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic, polymorphism

I am a student, so I don't know if my question is wrongly placed. I know that polymorphism is commonly achieved in OOP through method overriding, function overloading, and so on. But is it a concept exclusive to OOP languages? If not, could you provide examples on how to achieve it in non-OOP languages, including C but not exclusive to it? (So far I have some Java, C++, C, Javascript, and PHP experience)

Thanks.

Comment: Sure, pick your favorite statically typed functional language and the typing system will likely support polymorphism e.g. Haskell.

Comment: - https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism
 - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Polymorphism

Comment: Remember that the original C++ compiler was just translating the C++ code to plain C code. So it can definitely be done with non-OOP languages (although it might take some work).

Comment: @Some No, that's not what cfront (the original C++ compiler)  did - it was a true compiler that emitted C rather than assembly language, as do many modern compilers. C With Classes was a preprocessor, but the language it processed wasn't C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymorphism is not exclusive to OOP, or even OOP-like systems, but as you point out, they were conceived to give a standard pattern to what was considered to be a universal idea in software.  It can be simulated in languages that don't have first class support for it (and has syntactic help in some, for example lua).

In old procedural languages, one uses the same tricks C++ does, just more or less explicitly; often a void * to some dynamically allocated data along with a number of function pointers for operations on it.  It's exemplified to a degree by the standard library [qsort](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Sortable {
    char *(*toString)(struct Sortable *p);
} Sortable;

typedef struct AThing {
    Sortable p;
    int value;
} AThing;

typedef struct BThing {
    Sortable p;
    const char *str;
} BThing;

int sortableCompare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int res;
    Sortable *aa = *((Sortable **)a);
    Sortable *bb = *((Sortable **)b);
    char *astr = aa->toString(aa);
    char *bstr = bb->toString(bb);

    res = strcmp(astr, bstr);

    free(astr);
    free(bstr);

    return res;
}

char *AThing_toString(Sortable *p) {
    AThing *self = (AThing*)p;
    char *res = malloc(15);
    snprintf(res, 15, "%d", self->value);
    return res;
}

char *BThing_toString(Sortable *p) {
    BThing *self = (BThing*)p;
    return strdup(self->str);
}

AThing *createIntSortable(int i) {
    AThing *self = malloc(sizeof(*self));
    self->p.toString = AThing_toString;
    self->value = i;
    return self;
}

BThing *createStringSortable(const char *str) {
    BThing *self = malloc(sizeof(*self));
    self->p.toString = BThing_toString;
    self->str = str;
    return self;
}

int main() {
    Sortable *array[3];

    array[0] = &createIntSortable(1)->p;
    array[1] = &createStringSortable("hi")->p;
    array[2] = &createIntSortable(3)->p;

    qsort
        ( array // auto decay and coerce to void*
        , sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]) // nelem
        , sizeof(array[0]) // elem size
        , &sortableCompare // compare function
        );
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); ++i) {
        char *p = array[i]->toString(array[i]);
        printf("%d %s\n", i, p);
        free(p);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); ++i) {
        // To be more fancy, make a destructor in p                                                                                                                       
        free(array[i]);
    }
}
```

go and rust are not strictly object oriented, but use interface and duck-type conversions to give all types a lot of the same properties as objects.  You can decorate anything with methods and choose whether the self parameter is by reference or by value.

Haskell has type classes, which is kind of similar to the go and rust style of polymorphism in that a person who provides a type provides an implementation of an interface on that type (for example, an object that can act as a list might implement [Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html)).  Any function that takes objects implementing monoid can then receive an automatic coercion of the object to the Monoid typeclass implementation.

In functional languages that don't have type classes (and even much of the time in haskell), people do polymorphism by writing generic higher-order functions and then passing in sets of operations on the objects they care about.  In this way, you can have containers, filters, transformers and such that don't know what kind of thing they work on, but undertake a set of operations the user provides based on their own objective.  A good full example of this is [elm-astar](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/krisajenkins/elm-astar/2.1.2/AStar-Generalised) because it implements A* in a language that doesn't have any polymorphism facilities of its own.  It gains some terseness compared to C because while polymorphism isn't builtin, generic types are.

Comment: In retrospect, the elm example is more an example of genericity than polymorphism.  I had in mind the idea of the user having operations on a union type that then are called by more generic code.  The important part is that the operations the user specifies can handle any of the union alternatives.  I've written on this topic a couple of times on medium: https://medium.com/@prozacchiwawa/the-im-stupid-elm-language-nugget-13-84ba8539ebc4#.mm9ed7gha ..  Genericity is a prerequisite for this to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

### From definition:

> "In programming languages and type theory, polymorphism (from Greek πολύς, polys, "many, much" and μορφή, morphē, "form, shape") is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types.A polymorphic type is one whose operations can also be applied to values of some other type, or types".

Adding to Neil's answer. Polymorphism isn't only inheritance-based, even though **generalisation** suits it extremely well. In C++ you can with some more effort use STL's [std::variant](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) to apply **polymorphism**.

### Further reading and citations:

-[Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

-[Another polymorphism](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2016/02/27/another-polymorphism/)

Answer (score 0):

> But is it a concept exclusive to OOP languages?

Sort of. It's the defining attribute of an OO language. The ability to select behaviour at run-time dependent on what object or objects are involved in a function call is what OOP is all about.

But of course there are many otherv kinds of polymorphism. For example, C++ supports compile-time polymorphism via templates. But many people would say this is not OOP.